# Add prefixes and namespaces to XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces

I'm working in a Mexican tax calculation program and the government provided the following XSD file http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd, with xsd.exe help I have converted it to a C# class which is quite big so I'll just provide a link to it in order to no bloat this post with code:  http://pastebin.com/r3VCgFMU.

After filling SOME of the class fields (So the example doesn't get too big) I tried to serialize the XML as follows:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlNameSpace.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlNameSpace.Add("schemaLocation", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd");
xmlNameSpace.Add("cfdi", "www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3");
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter("c:\\temp\\pruebas.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Comprobante));

xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, comprobante, xmlNameSpace);
xmlTextWriter.Close();
```

Which gives me this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd" version="3.2" fecha="0001-01-01T00:00:00" subTotal="0" total="0" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" xmlns="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">
  <Emisor rfc="DERH9145202V4">
    <DomicilioFiscal calle="Calle1" colonia="Colonia" municipio="municipio" estado="estado" pais="pais" codigoPostal="07000" />
    <RegimenFiscal Regimen="Peque" />
  </Emisor>
</Comprobante>
```

As we can see in an example provided by the government (ftp://ftp2.sat.gob.mx/asistencia_servicio_ftp/publicaciones/solcedi/ejemplo1%20cfdv3.xml) my generated file lacks some points:

```
<Comprobante... should be <cfdi:Comprobante 
<Emisor.. should be <cfdi:Emisor 
and so on and so forth with all elements...
xmlns:schemaLocation should be xsi:schemaLocation  
I'm getting and additional xmlns="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" at the end of the Comprobante declaration
```

How can I achieve this changes in my xml? :D

Comment: You don't need to make any changes. The two documents are identical. Please see if http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml-namespaces/info helps you at all. If it doesn't help, then please say so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was solved by a MSDN staff guy, if anyone has the same problem just add:

```
[XmlAttribute(Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
public string schemaLocation = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 cfdv32.xsd";
```

either to the root class generated by the xsd.exe or to a partial class

(In this example

```
public partial class Comprobante {

        [XmlAttribute(Namespace = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
        public string schemaLocation = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 cfdv32.xsd";
...
}
```